# Unexpected value 'MsAdalAngular6Module' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, jestjs, adal

i'm working with angular 13 and implementing Adal Library. So my problem is that i have some test failing and don't know why.

This is my app.module
[image]

This is my app.component.spec.ts

[image]

The app.component.ts is empty because is almost an empty app.

This is the error i get. I use jest for unit tests.
[image]

Can you figure out what am i missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am thinking your `MsAdalAngular6Module` in the `.spec.ts` file needs a `.forRoot` just like in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Ok, will try with that. Thanks

Comment: Any success in this one?